# I have problems to store the result from a count command inside of while

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I get this error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_med_rankingfinall, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I need to assign the value from count to `@total` in each cycle of while.

Thank you in advance

```
declare @Total int = 0
declare @contador int = 0

while @contador <= 22
begin
    select @total = (select  
                         cod_medico,
                         count(@dato)) /*AS Cantidad_de_citas_completadas*/
    from 
        Registro_citas
    where 
        cod_medico = 900 + @contador 
        and estado_cita = @dato
    group by 
        cod_medico

    set @contador = @contador + 1
end
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Bad habits start early and are difficult to unlearn. Use SET to assign scalar values so that an error is thrown when the query that generates the value includes multiple rows. Here you are trying to set your variable to a resultset that contains multiple columns. That won't work even if you solve the syntax problem. I suspect you have taken the wrong path completely but cannot comment further based on a code fragment.

Comment: Even without the extra useless column in the subquery, this code doesn't make a lot of sense... you're assigning the result of a count for a specific `cod_medico` and then replacing it in the next iteration of the loop. What are you planning to do in each cycle of the loop that you couldn't do as a set all at once?

Comment: Thanks by each answer, Im try to assign the value from count to use later in a CASE statement, I cant to assign directly from count(), because the value was lost during iteration

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it should be

```
..
select @total = count(@dato)
from Registro_citas
where cod_medico = 900 + @contador and estado_cita = @dato;
..
```